# How to write a regex for this?

Tags: regex, grep, cut

Requirements: only grep/cut/join/regex.

I have data like this:

```sh
  798 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
15386 /usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service
16051 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
```

I want to extract rows data from the number to second ending space, like

```
798 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon
```

using only grep/cut/join with or without regex.

I have tried

```
grep -oe "[^ ][^ ]*  *[a-zA-Z\]*$"
```

but the result isn't as expected.

Comment: Try `grep -oP '^\s*\K\S+\s+\S+'` if you have a GNU grep. With a POSIX ERE, you might try something like `grep -oE '[0-9][^ ]*  +[^ ]+'`

Comment: You've excluded awk, whith which it'd be `awk '{print $1, $2}'`.

Comment: Yes, I know for awk. But I am restricted, not to use awk

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew It worked. Thanks. If possible add this as an answer.

Comment: If the numbers are at the start of the string `^[0-9]+ [^ ]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
# With GNU grep:
grep -oP '^\s*\K\S+\s+\S+' <<< "$s"
# With a POSIX ERE pattern:
grep -oE '[0-9][^ ]* +[^ ]+' <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/LQcl02)

- `o` - match output mode (not line)
- `P` - PCRE regex engine is used to parse the pattern

The PCRE pattern details:

- `^` - start of line
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the whole text matched so far
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s+\S+` - 1+ whitespaces and 1+ non-whitespace chars.

The POSIX ERE pattern matches

- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `[^ ]*` - 0+ chars other than space
- `+` - 1 or more spaces
- `[^ ]+` - 1+ chars other than a space.